# Comparing 2 string keeps returning false

Tags: javascript, string, compare, superagent

so im trying to check if the response i get back from a post request is "success".

```
onClick={ async () => {
    const response = await superagent.post(`http://localhost:3000/create/`).send({
        author: `${author}`,
        title: `${title}`,
        body: `${body}`,
        tag: `${tag}`,
    })
    const responseJSON = JSON.stringify(response.text)
    console.log(typeof responseJSON)

    console.log(responseJSON)
    if(responseJSON === "success"){
        
        setError('good')
    }else{
        setError('error try again')
    }
}}
```

ive console.logged the responseJSON and it shows that the value is infact a string and is "success" but when i compare it to "success" using the === operator it just returns false.
why is this?

Comment: `'success'` is not a valid JSON, and can never be a result of `JSON.stringify`. If `response.text` was `'success'`, `responseJSON` would be `'"success"'`. `'"success"' !== 'success'`.

Comment: @Amadan beat me to it by a hair!

Comment: Why are you doing `JSON.stringify(response.text)`? `response.text` is already a string.